# Recharts xAxis coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, recharts

I didn't find any information about Xaxis coordinates. 
On a screenshot I'm trying to fit all dots according to specific date, however, sometimes the dot goes over the Xaxis. 
And my question is how can I get to know Xaxis length to make some measurements for my dots ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5qoA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to make sure you dot is inside the extent of the axis?

If so use padding in the XAxis:

```
     <XAxis type="number" dataKey="x" height={40}
        scale="time" domain={xDomain}
        padding={{ left: 10, right: 10 }}
        tick={{ fontFamily: 'sans-serif', fontSize: '0.8rem' }}
        tickFormatter={props.xTickFormater}
     >
```

It's how I keep the bars "inside".

[image]